# miscalculation of distance calculation of dbgeography

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am using EF with a MSSQL DB and I am struggling with a spatial query:
I am using the user location to search for restaurants ordered by distance here is the code:

```
DbGeography userLocation = DbGeography.FromText(userLocationWKT, 4326);
            return (from branch in DbContext.Branches
                    let distance = userLocation.Distance(branch.Location)
                    orderby distance ascending
                    where branch.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()) && branch.Location != null
                    select new BranchAndDistance { Branch = branch, Distance = distance }).ToList();
```

the user location WKT is `POINT (32.78786115814 35.0162102747709)`. In my test case I am sending a query that returns one restaurant with `Lat=32.1300848 & Long=34.7919443` But the distance I am getting is 370237 meters which is way off.

The next image shows the QuickWatch window for the restaurant location details:
[image]
Notice that in the ProviderValue text it shows `POINT (34.7919443 32.1300848)` as if it replaces the Lat and Long but the actual values seem OK
So I conducted some more tests, since I am holding the lat and long values in separate variables I could test the following:

```
double? distance = Branch.Location.Distance(userLocation);
DbGeography branchLocation = DbGeography.FromText(string.Format("POINT ({0} {1})",
                                Branch.Latitude,.Branch.Longitude), 4326);
double? distance2 = branchLocation.Distance(userLocation);
```

The `distance` variable had the same incorrect distance value of 370237.85926851362
but the `distance2` variabel had the correct distance value of 65061.945208184392 
How can this be?
I have also checked in the SQL Azure database managment and according to that the `Location` property (which yields an incorrect distance result) is spot on
[image: when checking in SQL Azure it shows the correct location]

Have I missed something? What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

Your WKT for your user is not what you think it is. Specifically, that is a point that has (latitude, longitude) = (35.0162102747709, 32.78786115814). Here's a little T-SQL to show that:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
SELECT @g = geography::STPointFromText('POINT (32.78786115814 35.0162102747709)', 4326);

SELECT @g.Lat, @g.Long;
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that I got the cooridinates mixed and the first value is in fact longitude while the other one is latitude? I actually read about the WKT probably missed something.

Comment: Yes. Try switching them around and see if the results look more like you'd expect them to.